# Different paddings for text-background-padding in Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is it possible to specify different values for top/right/bottom/left paddings for node's label background in Cytoscape?

Currently this works for me: `'text-background-padding': '6px'`

But this doesn't: `'text-background-padding': '10px 20px 30px 40px'`

Comment: I looked at the cytoscape.js code, and seems that it doesn't support different padding value for each side. It uses single value in the position and size calculations of text-background.

Comment: `var padding = ele.pstyle( 'text-background-padding' ).pfValue;`